# Jquery DataTable on scroll paging

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have used Jquery DataTable with Sql Server Databse.

I have table with around 50K rows so i want to use its on Scroll dynamic paging

I have set folllowing properties for the same

```
 "bServerSide": true,
 "bScrollCollapse": true,
 "bScrollInfinite": true,
```

In Server side method , added bellow parameters

```
int iDisplayStart, int iDisplayLength
```

In Sql server i use this two parameters to get data

```
    SELECT  top @iDisplayLength   q.TotalRowsId, q.Id 
   FROM    (  
  Select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY U.SrNo) AS rn,160 as [TotalRowsId], U.ITEMCode    as[Id]
   ) q  
   WHERE rn > @IdisplayStart     
 ORDER BY q.Id desc
```

But Its not working fine, display count more then available data,no ajax call at regular interval etc.

Please help me
thanx

Comment: Can you post all the javascript related to datatables?